# Delimiters inside a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a spec that is saying that a certain field needs to be in the format "XX/XXXX/XXXXX". How do I add in read-only /'s inside of a textbox?

Comment: read-only /'s inside of a textbox ?! like `input` inside `textarea` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax toolkit has control: [MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for JQuery will let you require that users include the slashes in their input.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a maskedtextbox.  This isn't a standard asp.net control but several third party control libraries include masked textboxes.

Try googling asp.net Masked Textbox

http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/item.aspx?i=387

If you want to spend some money I use telerik controls for asp.net ajax telerik.com

Answer (score 0):

You could write a javascript event handler that handles the onkeypress event and adds/removes slashes in the appropriate places.